# getValue when the mousewheel stop rolling

Tags: javascript, html, mousewheel

I'm new in programming and I'm looking for a mouse-scroll action, my `onmouseup` command is working but I can't find a mouse-croll action.

I need to `getValue` when the mouse-scroll stopped rolling and not all the scrollactions on the way.

It will be a great help if somebody can help me out. This is my code I'm using.

```
<div tabindex="0" id="mup" class="my results"
    style="width:649px;height:649px;"
    onmouseup="javascript:getValue('','')"
    mousescroll="javascript:getValue('','')">
```

Comment: You can't, closest you'll get is to use a delay after each scroll, and if the window hasn't scrolled within that delay, you'll assume the user stopped scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for the `onmousewheel` and `onwheel` events:

```
<div id="scroll" onwheel="onWheel();" onmousewheel="onWheel();">
```

And then you will need a timer to check when the scrolling is done:

```
var theTimeout;
function onWheel(){
    clearTimeout(theTimeout);
    theTimeout=setTimeout(function(){
        doSomething();
    },500);
};
```

See this [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/nQHzL/).

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast reply, This code is working and making me a happy person. I can go to bed now:-).